# How can I add Google scopes later?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have an Angular 4 app that uses **Firebase UI (web)** with Google auth.  For our company staff users, I need to ask for more permission scopes than non-staff users. I don't necessarily need those extra scopes right away, though.

I'm thinking that the login screen will have a "staff login" checkbox that toggles the config.  However, the `new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())` call has already been made.

- Is it bad if I call `ui.start()` a second time with a different config?
- Or: is there something I should make sure I do to cleanly dispose of
  the prior AuthUI before creating a new one?
- Or: **(ideally)** is there a way to simply force a prompt later for additional scopes, only when needed?

Comment: If you're only using Google sign-in, you could also try directly using the signInWithPopup/signInWithRedirect methods in Firebase. This will let you set different parameters for every call.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-render the widget with:

`ui.reset();
ui.start('#firebaseui-container', myNewConfig);`